# How to console log the data from another react component when clicking a button?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Here is my button in one of my component files that opens up the form modal:

```
<Button onClick={() => setOpen(true)}
        style={{
          cursor: "pointer",
        }}>
        REQUEST
      </Button>
      <FormDialog isOpen={open} handleClose={() => setOpen(false)} />
```

Here is the form dialogue component. I want the data from all two text fields to be console logged when I click the following button that I have commented out in the code. Any help is appreciated!

```
export default class FormDialog extends React.Component<{ isOpen: boolean; handleClose: () => void }, {}>
 {
  render() {
    return (
      <Dialog
        open={this.props.isOpen}
        onClose={this.props.handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
      >
        <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Send Request</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <TextField
            autoFocus
            margin="dense"
            id="standard-read-only-input"
            label="Contact Name"
            defaultValue="John"
            InputProps={{
              readOnly: true,
            }}
          />
          <TextField
            autoFocus
            margin="dense"
            id="i"
            label="I"
            fullWidth
          />
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={this.props.handleClose} color="primary">
            Cancel
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={this.props.handleClose} color="primary">
            Send Request    //this is the button to click and then further log data
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you need either to keep input values in state and handle their's onChange events or set up a form and handle submit separately

Answer (score 0):

Save the values from text field to state of the component and then pass it to `handleSendRequest` handler of the button:

```
type State = {
  name: string,
  i: string
}

type Props = {
  isOpen: boolean,
  handleClose: () => void,
  handleSendRequest: (values: State) => void
}

export default class FormDialog extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  state = { name: '', i: '' }

  onChange = event => {
    this.setState(prevState =>
      ({ ...prevState, [event.target.name]: event.target.value })
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { isOpen, handleClose, handleSendRequest } = this.props
    return (
      <Dialog
        open={isOpen}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
      >
        <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Send Request</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <TextField
            autoFocus
            margin="dense"
            id="standard-read-only-input"
            label="Contact Name"
            name="name"
            defaultValue="John"
            InputProps={{
              readOnly: true,
            }}
            onChange={this.onChange}
          />
          <TextField
            autoFocus
            margin="dense"
            id="i"
            name="i"
            label="I"
            fullWidth
            onChange={this.onChange}
          />
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
            Cancel
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={() => handleSendRequest(state)} color="primary">
            Send Request    //this is the button to click and then further log data
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    );
  }
}
```

And then you can receive the values in your main component:

```
<Button onClick={() => setOpen(true)}
        style={{
          cursor: "pointer",
        }}>
        REQUEST
      </Button>
      <FormDialog
         isOpen={open}
         handleSendRequest={values => {
            setOpen(false)
           console.log(values)
         }}
         handleClose={() => setOpen(false)}
      />
```

Comment: I'm using a class component and your solution is a function I'm confused now

Comment: Which version of `React` are you using?

Comment: its 16.13.1, I need to use class though

Comment: I've converted it to class component, as you're using handleClose in other buttons as well so I created a separate event handler for Send Request button which will accepts the values as well.

Comment: Thank you. But when I do     const { isOpen, handleClose, handleSendRequest } = this.props, I get the error:Property 'isOpen' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.

Comment: Are you using typescript?

Comment: Yes, using typescript

Comment: So you've to add types of State and props in the class component.

Comment: I get an error 'Binding element 'boolean' implicitly has an 'any' type.' when I do something like this:  const { isOpen: boolean, handleClose: handleClose: () => void }, handleSendRequest } = this.props;

Comment: It's not `const`, it's `type`. I've edited the answer. But you need to clear up these concepts through some documentation/tutorials first.

Comment: Thank you, I wil, but I still get the error on 'const { isOpen, handleClose, handleSendRequest }' after making all the above changes: Property 'handleSendRequest' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>